# Request for Image Dataset of Animal Skin Disease

Tags: data-request

I was wondering if there is a dataset that contains an image of animal skin disease, need it for training dataset for my final project to detect scabies in animal skin.  I couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: just any images? where have you looked/tried?

Comment: yes any image of animal skin disease, even helpful if a lot of them are scabies. i have tried searching in kaggle and all site recommended by google, but a lot of dataset come up are of skin disease for human